# Stacking Band ratio on Landsat 8?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, imagery, landsat-8

I have a question about Landsat 8 I am going to work on...

I am thinking about stacking all the bands however there are 15 m, 30m, and 100m

Do you stack all together ? This is to give the end-user to change their band ratio in ArcGIS.

or should I just stack first 3 band ratio for each such as

According to this website : http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/24/band-combinations-for-landsat-8/

4,3,2

7,6,4

5,4,3

and so on

I'd like to hear your input

Comment: unfortunely we dont have 10.2 yet....still on 10.1

Comment: Stack at least all bands with similar resolution together. You do not need to restrict your selection to 3 bands. The link you posted is only relevant for displaying certain topics with landsat images. You can choose theese band combinations also from the stacked image.

Comment: Consider also oversampling the thermal band to 30 m as well because it won't cost so much in file size.

Comment: @EikeMike  Thank you. That is what I thought. I am going to have to do about at leat 40 scenes to do for our region wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @EikeMike:

> Stack at least all bands with similar resolution together. You do not
>   need to restrict your selection to 3 bands. The link you posted is
>   only relevant for displaying certain topics with landsat images. You
>   can choose theese band combinations also from the stacked image.

and @user30184:

> Consider also oversampling the thermal band to 30 m as well because it
>   won't cost so much in file size.

Comment: The thermal bands are provided as oversampled layers by the USGS. As such, you can directly stack them with the other 30 m bands. Only the panchromatic band is provided as something other than 30 m (it is provided as a 15 m layer)

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen Feel free to edit my answer or to add a new one (so I can delete mine).  This is an area where I have no expertise and am merely trying to ensure that the question gets an answer rather than languishing on our unanswered list.